# Automatic Username Input

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a very simple line in VBA, I need a shared document to automatically record the name of the whomever entered information into a cell for audit purposes. The Code is:

```
Function GetUserName()
    GetUserName = Environ("USERNAME")
End Function
```

also tried:

```
Function GetUserName()
    GetUserName = Application.Username
End Function
```

In both cases, it works for me but returns #NAME? for any other user. Any ideas?

Comment: In the VB editor you need to insert a new module and place the function there.

Comment: I guess I'm confused. Is that not what I'm doing what I hit Alt+F11? That is where I am writing this, I then hit save and run my workbook. When I input data, it auto-inputs my name in the adjacent cell, but when any other user tries, the adjacent cell reads #NAME?

Comment: Do the other users enable macros when  prompted after opening?  Do they see any messages that macros have been disabled?

Comment: I don't think they are being prompted. Can I set it so they are always active, it won't be feasible for me to do it individually.

Comment: This is a per device setting and often controlled by the organization.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/macros-in-office-files-12b036fd-d140-4e74-b45e-16fed1a7e5c6